# Cannot use gdbus command against same arguments of dbus-send

Tags: d-bus

On Fedora GNOME Xorg session, I am using

```
$ dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor.GetIdletime
```

to retrieve the user idle time. Indeed I get message

```
method return time=1558965539.579835 sender=:1.19 -> destination=:1.97 serial=409 reply_serial=2
   uint64 17
```

But if I try to use gdbus command

```
$ gdbus call --system --dest org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor --object-path /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core --method org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor.GetIdletime
```

I get the error

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name is not activatable
```

Why I am not able to use gdbus command against the same arguments?
Thank you

Comment: dbus-send use session bus and you try gdbus with system bus.

Comment: @ctac_ thank you very much. You may want to fill an official answer so you can get a green mark

Comment: I don't look for reputation. Write your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @ctac - comments are designed for clarifying questions or answers, not for answers themselves. Please consider writing an answer, if not for the reputation, then for solving problems (and making this question "Answered"). Thank you!